# Starting a startup?

Tags: attracting-clients, software, programmer, startups

For young developers out there, is it a good idea to start their own startup or get a job while pursuing a university education?

For someone young, is a startup counted as experience?

For a single guy is this a good idea?

Is capturing a big market for small revenue a good strategy?

For someone from a third-world country where a possible 3-digit revenue is better than a local job with pip environment is it a good idea?

Is startup good for learning and professional growth?

Does hard work and commitment guarantee success?

what I have tried: I have been working on an idea for about 3-4 months. My basics are all done. I have only slept 8hrs in the last 5 days. I am committed as it is better than what I was doing for cooperate anyway .As only guy I sometimes feel useless and worthless; regardless I keep on hustling. I don't know if it's a good idea or not. I did full time job along university and best thing is I am not even a software engineer. I am doing electrical engineer along.

About domain I have about 2 years of experience now in software development. Mentor: I highly admire Elon Musk. Plan right now: I am earning passive income from crypto trading which supports me financially, so that I can focus on my work more.

In the future I would love to work in the USA. Someone like me will be valuable or no?

Answer (score 4):

Let me start with the easy answer: "Hard work and commitment almost guarantees success?" No. All that does is to give you either bigger muscles or callouses on your hands. I recommend getting some sleep.

In order for hard work to pay off, it has to be directed towards something that someone else will pay for. There are a lot of things people have built that were useful, but nobody wanted to pay for. The first thing that a startup has to ask is: "Who will pay for this?" After you get some sleep, start figuring out how to find someone who has the need you are trying to fill and ask them how much they would pay for getting that need filled.

If you find customers for what you want to build and you satisfy them, that would be fantastic experience - but not for a software engineer position. It would be fantastic experience for a management position.

Comment: Pretending to be a customer of your own service is a good idea? Common thing i have heard is if you dont like your own app no one is going to like it either.So if i got customer aswell i feel satisfied.am i on right path?

Comment: Using your own software for your own purposes is good, but doesn't change the question about success. Making something that everyone uses but doesn't pay you for is not a success. Eli Whitney invented the cotton gin. Nearly everyone stole his idea and he got almost no payments for that invention. He vowed never to invent something quite so valuable that nobody would pay him for. His next invention was manufacturing interchangeable parts which is the basis for much of modern manufacturing. He got paid for that.

Comment: Great point! Having a good idea or good software IS NOT ENOUGH on its own. You need to identify a need in a market that your software targets, otherwise you will have a hard time attracking customers.